# CSS grid justify-self not centering element in Safari

Tags: html, css, vue.js, safari, webkit

I have this `div` (mobile menu) that is centered in `chrome` via `css grid` and `justify-self` property but in safari it sits on the left side of the screen (behind the instagram icon):

[image]

Is there a `webkit` property I can use or do you have any other idea how to fix this?

I am using `vue.js` to render the html.

Comment: Check on can I use to see if it's supported and if you need a prefix.

Comment: Could you please share some code sample?

Answer (score -1):

Using the `align-self` property should work.
[W3Schools reference for the same](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-self.asp)

Comment: I've replaced `justify-self` with it but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Well, on the reference page it says that `align-self` is supported by Safari, so I don't know why it isn't working. Try using margins or Bootstrap for the same. I think Bootstrap should solve the problem.

Comment: Also, if it works please don't forget to Upvote my answer.

Comment: You can also code the website in a way that it can recognise that the user is using Safari and set a `margin-top` according to which iPhone they're using. Its a long fix, so I think you should use it as a last resort.